# MySQL - INSERT queries taking long time

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a table with about 10.000 rows. 
Structure of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `demands` (
  `cycle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `market_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Keys:

- PRIMARY (cycle_id, subject_id, market_id, price)
- FK1 (market_id)
- FK2 (subject_id)
- FK3 (currency_id)

Query like this offen takes long time (about 1s):

```
INSERT INTO poptavky VALUES 
  (4, 'user', 17, 110, 'pound', 110) ,
  (4, 'user', 17, 90, 'pound', 120) , 
  (4, 'user', 17, 70, 'pound', 130) ;
```

Where could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Which takes 1 second?  Inserting 3 rows?  Or inserting all 10K?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one of the other tables.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are not on a very high end server and your problems are compounded by having far too many indexes.

This index on it's own is rather a massive one:

```
PRIMARY (cycle_id, subject_id, market_id, price)
```

It spans four columns and two of them are varchar columns. That in itself will not be a problem. but you have three more:

```
FK1 (market_id)
FK2 (subject_id)
FK3 (currency_id)
```

After each insert the database has to recalculate the indexes and that takes a lot of time when the number of indexes and/or index length is high. Particularly when lots of data is inserted all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this kind of request :

```
INSERT INTO client (prenom, nom, ville, age)
 VALUES
 ('Rébecca', 'Armand', 'Saint-Didier-des-Bois', 24),
 ('Aimée', 'Hebert', 'Marigny-le-Châtel', 36),
 ('Marielle', 'Ribeiro', 'Maillères', 27),
 ('Hilaire', 'Savary', 'Conie-Molitard', 58);
```

The SGBD will better know where put the data.

Nevertheless try with just 1000 rows and see if it's as slower as 10000 rows.

Comment: Although it is wise to spell out the column names, the performance difference is insignificant.